# How can I properly join these strings together (by column then row)?

Tags: python, string, join

I have the following piece of python code that I just can't get to work the way I want to. Here's the code:

```
l = [['#' for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
o = ['\n'.join(r) for r in l]
print ''.join(r for r in o)
```

Here's the current program output:

```
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
##
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
```

Here's what I want the program to output:

```
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
```

How can I change to code to have the desired output?

Comment: `l = [['#' for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]; o = [''.join(r) for r in l]; print '\n'.join(r for r in o)`

Comment: Strictly you never need to form big string l in the first place if all you want to do is print the identical string '##########\n' 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use join:

```
print '\n'.join( ''.join('#' for column in range(10)) for row in range(10))
```

but much easier would be:

```
print ('#'*10 + '\n')*10
```

Comment: The second solution has an extra newline at the end. Needs `…[:-1]` to cut it, or `print …,` so that `print` does not automatically add a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You simply join in the wrong order:

```
l = [['#' for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
o = [''.join(r) for r in l]    # join the columns
print '\n'.join(r for r in o)  # join the rows
```

Or more easy to read:

```
'\n'.join((''.join(r) for r in l))
```

Or without `l`:

```
(('#' * 10 + '\n') * 10)[:-1]
```

Or even:

```
'''##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########'''
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 for x in range(1,11):
     print "#"*10
```

output:

```
########## 
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
########## 
##########
```

explanation: if you multiply a string with a number, it will produce the number of repeating string  
Demo:

```
 >>> "a"*10
 'aaaaaaaaaa'
 >>> "b"*6
 'bbbbbb'
 >>>
```

Comment: `range(10)` is sufficient

Comment: i know, it just a  different representation, range(10) is `0-9` and range(1,11) is `1-10` is just needed count to 10 , it can be also range(90,100) or any interval of 10

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['#' for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
print '\n'.join(''.join(r) for r in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Strictly you don't need to form string `l` in the first place (total waste of memory), since all you wanted to do is print the identical string `'##########\n'` 10 times.
2. `print` supplies the trailing `\n` so you don't need to explicitly `join()` that to each row.
3. And finally you don't need `join()` to replicate a string n times, just do `'#' * 10`

.

```
for _ in range(10):
    print '#' * 10  # all we need is one string-constant of length 10,
                    # if we only want to print it, not store it
```